Group representation over finite fields
In Isaacs' Character theory of finite groups, the theorem $9.14$ states that an absolutely irreducible over a field of prime characteristic can be realized over any subfield containing its character values.
He first shows this result for finite field using a lot of concepts associated to algebra representations so that he could use Wedderburn's theorem on finite division algebras and this proof seemed quite dense and confusing to me.
It occurred to me that there should be a more "direct" proof of this result by using Wedderburn's theorem directly on the endomorphism ring of the representation $($which is a division algebra by Schur lemma$)$ and by noticing that the endormorphism ring of a representation $($on a finite field$)$ is commutative iff the multiplicity of its irreducible components is always $1$.
While trying many times to prove this, I overlooked result that seemed intuitive to me:

Let $E/F$ be a field extension and $V$ be an irreducible $E$-representation of a finite group $G$. If $V$ is not realized over any intermediate field $K$ of $E/F$, then $V$ stays irreducible as an $F$-representation of $G$.

But this turned out to be false in general as someone pointed it out in this post "Changing the field of an irreducible representation leaves it irreducible".
Using this, it would have been easy to prove this result since it is easy to prove that if $E/F$ is a field extension and $V$ is a representation of character $\chi$ such that the values of $\chi$ are in $F$, then, the character of $V$ when viewed as an $F$-representation becomes $[E:F]\chi$.
We can then suppose that $F$ is a maximal subfield of $E$ without loss of generality and therefore, if $V$ could not be realized over $F$, my wrong assumption would have implied that $V$ is irreducible when viewed as an $F$-representation. Which would imply that $V \otimes_{F} E$ does not have a commutative endomorphism ring and therefore neither does $V$ $($viewed as an $F$-representation$)$. Then this contradicts the fact that it is irreducible by Wedderburn's theorem.
I rewrote this proof multiple times before realizing that I could not prove my assumption but I like this proof before seeing it crumble down before my
eyes.
Was this still a good idea or is there really no simpler proof of this result that does not involve too much of algebra theory ?

"the endormorphism ring of a representation is commutative iff the multiplicity of its irreducible components is always 1" is wrong. The quaternion group $Q8$ has a four-dimensional irreducible representation over real numbers. Name this irrep $W$, then $\text{End}_G(W) \cong \mathbb{H}$ and is not commutative.

Yes, I know. It is true on finite fields only because of Wedderburn's theorem. I'll add it in parenthesis.

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $L/K$ be an extension of finite fields and let $V$ be an absolutely irreducible $L[G]$-module and suppose that $K$ contains the character values of $V$. Let $\mathfrak{G}=\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$. Let $V_0$ be the restriction of $V$ to a $K[G]$-module. Then we have (this holds for any finite Galois extension):
$$L \otimes_K V_0 \cong \bigoplus_{\sigma \in \mathfrak{G}} V_{\sigma}$$ Here $V_{\sigma}$ denotes the conjugate of $V$ by $\sigma$. But if $\chi$ is the character of $V$, then the character of $V_{\sigma}$ is $\sigma \circ \chi$. By our assumption, the character values lie in $K$, so that $\sigma \circ \chi = \chi$ and hence $V_{\sigma} \cong V$. Thus $L \otimes_K V_0 \cong V^{[L:K]}$ as $L[G]$-modules.
Let $J$ denote the Jacobson radical. A module over an Artinian ring is semisimple iff it is annihalted by the Jacobson radical. It's well-known that in our siutation $J(L[G]) \cong L \otimes_K J(K[G])$. We get $0=J(L[G])V\supset J(K[G])V=J(K[G])V_0$, so $V_0$ is semisimple.
Next, let's consider endomorphism rings. Using that $V$ is absolutely irreducible, we get that $$M_{[L:K]}(L) \cong M_{[L:K]}(\mathrm{End}_{L[G]}(V))\cong \mathrm{End}_{L[G]}(V^{[L:K]})=\mathrm{End}_{L[G]}(L \otimes_K V_0)\\ \cong L \otimes_K \mathrm{End}_{K[G]}(V_0)$$ Due to Wedderburn's little theorem, this implies that $\mathrm{End}_{K[G]}(V_0) \cong M_{[L:K]}(K)$.
Due to the facts that $V_0$ is semisimple and has endomorphism ring $M_{[L:K]}(K)$, we conclude that $V_0=W^{[L:K]}$ for some absolutely irreducible $K[G]$-module $W$. But then $L \otimes_K V_0 = V^{[L:K]}$ implies that $L \otimes_K W=V$ and we're done.
